# A MySQL query error has occurred. Error number: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

When I login, I take this error:

**A MySQL query error has occurred. Error number: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

(my db is mysql)

Why I don't know. Help!!!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Very clear message! You tried to connect with user root and no password which doesn't grant you acces to the database. The credientials should be something else such as `root/root` ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: Take a back up of config.inc.php

Go to [WAMP_PATH] --> apps --> phpmyadmin.

Then find and open config.inc.php (in your text editor)

Find **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ”;** and change it with **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ‘admin’;** (You can put anything in place of admin as your password, this is only a test password).

Now find **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;** and replace it by **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;**.

Restart your wampserver.

Answer (score 0):

First Go To localhost/phpmyadmin

Click on users and check for user named 'root'.

Check if user 'root' has password or not and also check for privileges.

if root has password, than click on 'edit privileges'.

In change password tab, do your task,

if you want to remove password, check 'No Password' radio and if you want to change password

do that.